# Why is Jackson's expression for the force on a current distribution, ${\bf F} = \int {\bf J(x)} \times {\bf B(x)} d^3x$, missing an electric term?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, electric-current, charge

Reading Jackson I had a doubt about the following (3th ed, p.178)

> If a current density ${\bf J(x)}$ is in an external magnetic-flux density ${\bf B(x)}$, the elementary force law implies that the total force in the current distribution is:
>   \begin{equation}
> {\bf F} = \int {\bf J(x)} \times {\bf B(x)} d^3x
> \end{equation}

I understand that by *elementary force law* he's refering to ${\bf dF} = {\bf dJ \times B} = dq\ {\bf v \times B} = \rho\ d^3x\ {\bf v \times B}$. But $\rho$ accounts for other charged particles, which generate their own ${\bf E}$ fields, so why ${\bf E}$ cancels out in the end (for every possible ${\bf J}$)? Shouldn't it be ${\bf dF} = dq\ ({\bf E + v \times B})$? Is this only an approximation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the configuration includes regions with nonzero charge density in which an electric field is present, then yes, the total force will include an electric term
$$
\mathbf F_\mathrm{electric} = \int \rho(\mathbf x) \mathbf E(\mathbf x) d^3x.
$$
However, that is not what Jackson is describing. When he says

> a current density $\mathbf J(x)$

that does **not** imply a nonzero charge density $\rho(\mathbf x)$ moving with the velocity field $\mathbf v(\mathbf x) = \mathbf J(\mathbf x)/\rho(\mathbf x)$: it implies a current density $\mathbf J(\mathbf x)$ in a neutral region with a vanishing charge density $\rho(\mathbf x)=0$. Jackson's claim, that the only force for that configuration is magnetic, is **correct**, as is his expression for that magnetic force.

Now, that's not to say that in a real-world scenario that current density $\mathbf J(\mathbf x)$ isn't made up of moving charges, but the core point is that charge comes in both positive and negative flavours, and those can cancel out for $\rho(\mathbf x)$ without cancelling out for $\mathbf J(\mathbf x)$. (If you want a real-world example, grab the nearest electric cable that's carrying electric current. Is it electrically charged, or is it neutral?) In cases where $\rho(\mathbf x)$ vanishes, of course, the electric force also vanishes, and you're left only with the magnetic component.

And, moreover: *we don't need to know*, at all, what components make up a given current density, because the forces are completely determined once you know $\rho(\mathbf x)$ and $\mathbf J(\mathbf x)$, so it doesn't matter whether it's a sea of electrons moving over a sea of stationary positive ions versus, say, an ionized hydrogen plasma where there's a substantial current carried by the protons. This is why it's perfectly legitimate to say that you just want to consider

> a current density $\mathbf J(x)$,

implicitly setting $\rho(\mathbf x)\equiv 0$, and just roll with the consequences of that, without any further examination of what the microscopic picture actually looks like.